# Unable to Pass Byte[] to GraphQL Endpoint

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-js

I have client side code that converts a file upload to a `Uint8Array`

In my GraphQL API I have a field defined as follows

```
Field(c => c.Data, type: typeof(ByteGraphType));
```

I get the following error while calling the mutation

> Could not find conversion from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String,
>   System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object,
>   System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' to 'System.Byte'

Comment: graphql is json, just encode it :D - uploading files is supported - read docs

Comment: what type do i declare the field then?